# Как перейти на страницу гугл календаря, что бы повторно не входить в гугл

Tags: php, symfony, google-calendar-api

нужно добавить функционал что бы пользователь мог вносить в свой гугл календарь некоторые события, и если пользователь уже вошел в систему через гугл можно ли как то сразу переходить по ссылке на календарь? Вот мой код входа через гугл:

```
public function googleSigninAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($this->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('user.dashboard.current');
        }

        /* @var $client \Google_client */
        $client = $this->container->get('google.client.factory')->getClient();

        $state = uniqid('', true);
        $client->setState($state);
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $url = $client->createAuthUrl();
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $session->set(
            $this->container->getParameter('google_state_key'), $state
        );

        $ref = $this->generateUrl(
            'lesson.migrate',
            [],
            UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL
        );
        if (null !== $ref && $ref !== $request->getUri()) {
            $session->set('after_login_target', $ref);
        }

        $redirect = new RedirectResponse($url);

        return $redirect;
    }
```

`google.client.factory` ' это сервис, ключи берутся из `parameters.yml`

Comment: если вы авторизированы в гугле, то по ссылке https://calendar.google.com/calendar можно перейти на свой календарь. Вам по сути нужно просто обработать $client->isAccessTokenExpired()